# Using ap-hotspot to share a proxy connection

Tags: 14.04, hot-spot

I know I can use ap-hotspot to configure a wifi hotspot in normal connection. But what is I'm connected to internet via a socks proxy? How can I share internet to my mobile devices then?

Answer (score 3):

The `ap-hotspot` solution is slightly out of date and has the added disadvantages of being complicated and incompatible with socks proxies. A simpler solution is to use ubuntu's built in `network-manager` to create the hotspot as detailed by http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/

TCP traffic from the hotspot can be passed through the `ssh -D` socks proxy using `redsocks`. With `redsocks` installed and configured one can use `iptables` to redirect all traffic from the wifi hotspot to `redsocks` which then passes it through the socks proxy.

For instance if your wifi hotspot is on the `10.42.0.1/24` subnet and the incoming `redsocks` port is `12345` issue:

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12345
```

For a detailed set of instructions visit http://abidmujtaba.blogspot.com/2016/07/ubuntu-create-wifi-hotspot-access-point.html

Comment: How do I know the subnet range of my wifi hotspot?

Comment: `ip addr show dev <interface>` will have an `inet` field giving you the address and subnet. For interface `wlo1` running this command on my computer gives `inet 192.168.1.153/24` so I would use `192.168.1.0/24` in my `iptables` command.